# How to compare two list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 L1 = [8, 80, 53, 70, 90, 24, 40]
 L2 = [30, 255, 70, 90, 24, 0, 36, 54]

 for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
       if i==j and i+1 == j+1 and i+2 == j+2:
          ret = OK
          break
    if ret == OK:
       break
 if ret == OK:
    break
```

I have two list. Need to compare the list and if three consecutive items are same then it should return ok. The code above does the following but I would like to know a simple solution to achieve in Python.

Comment: Can it be any three consecutive items in both lists or do they need to have the same indexes?

Comment: @islamabdelmoumen when three consecutive items in list are same it should return true. the above code returns. But a simplified coding is appreciated.

Comment: @fafl any three consecutive items

Comment: Your code doesn't work right. Swap 90 and 24 in L1 to see.

Comment: i am not sure if your code realy working. 1. indentation is not correct. 2. where ret and OK come from, it has not defined yet? cmiwi

Comment: `if i==j and i+1 == j+1 and i+2 == j+2` I wonder the logic behind it.

Comment: well, if `i == j`, then it is simple math that `i+1 == j+1` and `i+2 == j+2` are also True. What do you actually want to compare?

Comment: _The code above does the following but I would like to know a simple solution to achieve in Python_ - no, the code is not doing anything - there are errors and everything it will ever return is `None`. and even if it run, it is not doing what you describe

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjung It is not a working code. It is logic that if three consecutive item are found return true

Comment: @buran it is not going to be true always. Need to find if three consecutive item of L1 exist in L2 and return true.

Comment: _it is not going to be true always_ you are not very good at math, do you? If i == j, then i+1 == j + 1  ALWAYS, as well as i + 2 == j + 2 ALWAYS... You probably are **thinking** of terms of indexes and accessing list elements by index, but that is not what your code does at all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the memory to create a set of all tuples from one list then this is the most efficient way. Convert one list to a set of all its tuples and then iterate over the other list. This runs in O(n) time and space complexity.

```
L1 = [8, 80, 53, 70, 90, 24, 40]
L2 = [30, 255, 70, 90, 24, 0, 36, 54]
 
triples = set()
for i in range(len(L1) - 2):
    triples.add((L1[i], L1[i+1], L1[i+2]))
for i in range(len(L2) - 2):
    triple = (L2[i], L2[i+1], L2[i+2])
    if triple in triples:
        print("Found", triple)
```

It prints `Found (70, 90, 24)`

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most efficient but this certainly seems to work:

```
L1 = [8, 80, 53, 70, 90, 24, 40]
L2 = [30, 255, 70, 90, 24, 0, 36, 54]

triplets = {t for t in zip(L1, L1[1:], L1[2:])}

for t in zip(L2, L2[1:], L2[2:]):
    if t in triplets:
        print('Found', t)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
Found (70, 90, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your function lighter you could just loop over elements that you know are in both lists:

```
L1 = [8, 80, 53, 70, 90, 24, 40]
L2 = [30, 255, 70, 90, 24, 0, 36, 54]

check = False
for i in range(len(L1)-2):
    for j in [ind for ind, x in enumerate(L2) if x == L1[i]]:
        if L1[i:i+3] == L2[j:j+3]:
            check = True
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L1 = [8, 80,1,2,3, 53, 70, 90, 24,1, 40]
L2 = [30, 255,1,2,3, 70, 90, 24,1, 0, 36, 54]
n=len(L1)
i=0
while i<n:
    z=0
    for v in L2:

        if L1[i]==v:
            z+=1
            i+=1

            if z>2:
                  print('OK')
        else:
            z=0  
    i+=1
```